# how to detect JFIF image type in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, jfif

I have laravel project that let user upload images and I can validate (jpeg/png) without problem.
the problem occur when users upload JFIF-image (which consider to be images/jpeg mime types) but the laravel intervention package show message "Encoding format (jfif) is not supported."
so, how to detect jfif during validation to prevent this.
I tried:

```
$request->file('image')->extension() //return jpeg
```

Comment: Tricky but check this seems to be a bug in intervention
https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/989

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the extension using

```
$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension()
```

Note that this function makes use of the `pathinfo()` function and so is based on the file name as per the comment on the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L94)